# Collapse recyclerview and show only last element

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I have a recyclerview with 3 rows maximum. This RV located on the top of my view. Below located container for my fragment. And I want to make only last element of my rv visible, when I will scroll content inside my fragment and show all elemenets of rv when I will on the top of my fragment content. How to do this?

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/my_recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="2dp"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Use NestedScrollView on top of LinearLayout

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to use nestedscrollview in your layout for proper scrolling of recyclerView and other views in your parent layout.

The second thing you can do is send only the last element of your list to the adapter.

like ,

```
ArrayList<Test> tempList=new ArrayList();

tempList.add(customList.get(customList.size()-1);
```

where customList is the Type of class data which are you sending as an argument to your adapter.

this way you can do your work.